# Will setting up DKIM on Google Apps interfere with mail sent from the web server using the same domain name

Tags: g-suite, dkim

I would like to set up DKIM on my domain for messages sent using Google Apps. I understand how to do this but I am concerned that if I have a DKIM DNS record for the domain, messages sent from the webserver itself (ie my website sends email in the form of password resets, order confirmations etc) they will be more likely to be treated as spam as they won't be signed in the same way as mail sent from GApps.

Have I understood this correctly and are there any implications of setting up DKIM for my domain for Google Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up DKIM with Google apps shouldn't affect your other e-mails. That said, you should set up DKIM on the webserver as well, so your password resets etc. benefit from the reputation boost DKIM gives.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know of any good guides to setting up DKIM on a webserver running nginx & postfix?

Comment: nginx won't have anything to do with it, it's all postfix and DNS config. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM if you're on Ubuntu. If you're on something else, a quick Google for your OS, Postfix, and DKIM will do the trick.